# Parabolic reflector and Feeds

Tags: rf, antenna

I was reading up on parabolic reflector designs ,specifically the prime fed design and I can't seem to understand how this design works so well? Won't a major portion of the power reflected off the reflector  be input to the feed thereby increasing the VSWR ? [image]

Also , would any reflector dish work with a feed . What would be the things apart from gain to keep in  mind while designing a dish given a feed .

Comment: Are you asking about transmitting or receiving specifically?  Remember, the design of a parabola, is such that (ideally) when receiving, the entire area of the dish focuses on the focal point, but when transmitting, all emissions from the focal point are sent from every point of the dish directly up (in your diagram above).  Focal Point occulsion is very small actually.

Comment: @RDrast I'm asking about transmitting , but the feed used is primarily a horn whose main beam direction is such that it would impinge on the reflector in such a way that most of it would get reflected back in the same direction when used as prime focus

Comment: In most parabolic reflectors I've seen, the "antenna" (whether feed-horn, dipole, yagi, etc.) has always been smaller than 1/4 the diameter of the reflector. using pi*r^2, that gives the max "aperture" of the antenna at 1/16th the aperture of the reflector; so small even in the most extreme cases. -- Also worthy of note: many parabolic reflectors are designed similar to yagi reflectors, in that the reflected signal arrives back at the D.E. (driven element) *in phase* & (with computer-simulated modelling/design) the whole system can be designed for a good impedance match/VSWR.

Answer (score 1):

A dish has a radiating area of approximately that of a circle. That area being \$\frac{\pi D^2}{4}\$ = 0.785 sq metres for a diameter of 1 metre.

If the feed point is 10% the diameter of the dish then it will obscure an area of 0.00785 sq metres i.e. one-hundredth of the dish area.

So if 100 watts are being projected by the dish approximately 1 watt is wasted by the area of the feedpoint. That is a small price to pay even if that power were totally lost (and that isn't always the case).

Answer (score 0):

Given communication link budgets attend to 10dB or 2dB losses, with an optional 20dB for RAIN, the feedhorn occlusion ---- 0.1dB ---- gets buried into the "gain" of the dish.

Some antennas have the feed located OFF-AXIS, to prevent even that loss. Go look at DirectTV dishes up on the eaves of houses.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind going for offset feed but prime focus cassegrain and gregorian are still extremely popular despite having these problems . Is there a reason why people tend to use prime focus ?

Comment: I think most people are not concerned about that extra 0.1dB loss, nor concerned about spurious off-axis vulnerability to jamming from sides of the dish. Extra metal means more surfaces to intercept trash and place that trash into the dish.